# What is an example of a use case for the pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_df() variant, that takes an iterator of pd.Series?

Tags: pyspark

It is not clear to me why there is a park.sql.functions.pandas_df() variant taking an iterator of pd.Series in addition to the one that just takes a single pd.Series. What would be a situation where I need the former and cannot equally well use the latter?

Comment: This might be of help also look at the performance. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html

Comment: @venky__ I know this link, but still I don't get why this is needed.